# Ghostscript only antialiasing some text?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I have a PDF that is an architectural floor plan with a bunch of room labels in it. Using ghostscript's `-sDEVICE=txtwrite` option I can see that all of the labels are indeed text and not graphics/images.

However, when I convert the PDF to png using this command:

```
gs \
  -sDEVICE=png16m \
  -dUseArtBox \
  -r100 \
  -sPageList=1 \
  -dAutoRotatePages=/None \
  -dGraphicsAlphaBits=1 \
  -dTextAlphaBits=4 \
  -dAlignToPixels=1 \
  -dGridFitTT=2 \
  -dMaxBitmap=4000000000 \
  -o output.png input.pdf
```

Some of the text is anti-aliased:

[image: anti-aliased text]

And other parts are not anti-aliased and look terrible:

[image: not anti-aliased text]

I can see that "QUIET 8013" appears in the text dump of the pdf. So why isn't it anti-aliased?

My goal is to anti-alias the text and not anti-alias the graphics. Interestingly though, if I set `-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4` it anti-aliases the graphics AND the "QUIET 8013" text.

Comment: I haven't yet looked at the file. But remember that there are type 3 fonts whose glyphs are defined as pdf content streams and as such can contain anything, even small bitmaps...

Comment: If you think you have found a bug in Ghostscript then the obvious thing to do is to raise a bug report at bugs.ghostscript.com. If GraphicsAlphaBits causes the text to be anti-aliased then obviously Ghostscript thinks that text is graphics not text. No clue why of course.

Comment: OK so the 'problem' is the way the text is drawn. It is written with text rendering mode 2, fill and then stroke, presumably for a 'fake bold' effect. It is also rather small (about 8 points). The TextAlphaBits parameter only affects the 'fill' part of the text. So the text **is** being anti-aliased, but the stroke which follows writes over the top of the anti-aliasing effectively erasing it. This is more pronounced on characters consisting of horizontal or vertical lines, curves can more easily escape this. So no bug, it's jut the way the text is written.

Comment: Obviously if you apply GraphisAlphaBits then that affects the stroke, so it **appears** that the text is being anti-aliased, but it isn't, its the stroke around it which is.

Comment: Thanks but I'm fully employed by Artifex :-) There's nothing wrong with the text as such; it's simply that it's using a text rendering mode that doesn't work well with the Ghostscript text anti-aliasing. That code was written before PDF was a thing and so it doesn't treat fill and then stroke as being text, only the 'fill' part gets anti-aliased because in PostScript that's all you can do with text. We can't change the behaviour because people would complain. I might run it past a colleague as I have a sort of half-assed idea how it might be made to work **only** for PDF input.

Comment: You could open an enhancement bug report over at bugs.ghostscript.com, because my memory is notoriously awful.....

Comment: Hmm I added some code to Ghostscript's PDF interpreter to handle this, but I have mislaid the original file. And someone (presumably one of the moderators because I certainly can't do this) has removed a bunch of the comments, destroying some of the sense of the thread) and I think removing the URL to the original file. Helpful, not.....

Comment: @KenS New link: https://www.docdroid.net/d1ZcLhJ/8-pdf

Comment: @Quick, thanks for that. I can confirm that my commit (not yet in golden but I'm trying to get it in before the next release) does anti-alias the stroke on the text now. The Capital T and H do not appear anti-aliased, not sure why, but the remaining text does. I also need to revisit this old bug report https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=698335 and see if it is improved. I've still got 24 hours so hopefully I can get this squeezed in.

Comment: This commit https://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=commit;h=63acbe4fb049bd63c3575ef8696d6d7ec33322ab should (I hope) resolve the problem. Because the text is so small you may need to render it at a higher resolution to see any difference; I used 300 dpi to see it more clearly.

Comment: Wow, thanks @KenS, we will integrate that after the next release!